# Does synchronizing an object also synchronize its parameters?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have an object  A(Object1, Object2). If I synchronize A does that also synchronize Object1 and Object2 so two threads can't access them at the same time? I couldn't find an answer anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't even restrict access to `A`. You need to read up on synchronization some more.

Comment: Do you mean "parameters"?

Comment: @shmosel yes Parameters! I've fixed it. I've been reading about thread synchronization and my impression is that if I use a synchronized block i can restrict access to one thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: Synchronization doesn't restrict access to an object, it restricts access to a code block. That is, any code block synchronizing on the same object.